# Laravel & Vue: Communication between different Vue components split by Laravel views

Tags: laravel, vue.js, components, communication

I am using Vue all over the place in my Laravel project. I have a couple of views, and a dozen components inside these views that I have registered in app.js. Inside these components I have more components. Now the fun part starts when I want one component to communicate with another. What is the most efficient way to exchange information between different Vue components given that these are seperated by different laravel views (via include)?

Comment: I would use a communication bus: https://medium.com/@jilsonthomas/create-a-global-event-bus-in-vue-js-838a5d9ab03a

Comment: Thank you @El_Matella, that is precisely what I will be doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way for many components across your project to update when there are state changes would be to use VueX.

VueX moves your entire app state, methods, etc. to a centralized location that your components can leverage.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html

Comment: Thank you very much. So for simple applications, you can use events. For some cases you may need [Non Parent-Child Communication](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Non-Parent-Child-Communication). And for really complex apps, you can use [state management](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html), like with VueX for example.

Comment: Correct. VueX is overkill for most things but anytime you have lots of nested components spread out amongst many pages, it simplifies things a lot

Comment: It does, I decided to use it. Pretty sure it makes my application far more efficient.